# Hash function to determine whether two vectors had an equal entry on some row

Tags: hash-function

Do you know about a hash function, that approximates (in probability) the following function:

**Original function:**
Two vectors collide if there is a row where their entries are equal.
$$
\text{E.g., }\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
2\\
6
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ collide (both=2 on row 2),}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1\\
3
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
2\\
6
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ do not collide.}
$$

**Hash Function:**
Do you know about a hash function where the hashes of two vectors $u,v$ are equal (with high probability) if they they had an equal entry on some row (so, $\exists i\colon u_i=v_i$)?

$$
\text{So,}\quad P(h(v)=h(u)) \quad \text{should be high for vectors that have a same entry on some row}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think such a hash function should exist because the collision rule that you defined is not transitive. For example, $A=(1,2,3)^T$ collides with $B=(1,4,5)^T$ at $1$, and $B$ collides with $C=(7,6,5)^T$ at $5$, but $A$ and $C$ do not collide. But for any hash function $h$, if $h(A)=h(B)$ and also $h(B)=h(C)$, then $h(A)=h(C)$. There are too many such examples, so the chances of errors for an "approximate" hash function should be very high.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer! I like this nonexistence proof.